# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paste')...but why?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

When I run the code below and click the custom toolbar button I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paste')

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any insight?

JS

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea#taskEmail',
height: 550,
menubar: false,
plugins: 'table link',
toolbar:
  'tokenButton | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | link anchor',
setup: function (editor) {
  var taskDetails = function () {
    tinymce.activeEditor.dom.setHTML(
      tinymce.activeEditor.dom.select('#emailBody'),
      '<tr><td style="width:30%">Name</td><td style="width:70%">!EmployeeName!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Task Name</td><td style="width:70%">!TaskName!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Task Description</td><td style="width:70%">!TaskDescription!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Date Assigned</td><td style="width:70%">!DateAssigned!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Due Date</td><td style="width:70%">!DueDate!</td></tr>',
    )
  }

  editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('tokenButton', {
    text: 'Available Tokens',
    fetch: function (callback) {
      var items = [
        {
          type: 'menuitem',
          text: 'Task Detail Template',
          onAction: function (_) {
            editor.insertContent(taskDetails())
          },
        },
      ]
      callback(items)
    },
  })
},
content_style:
  'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:1.25rem }',
})
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/KEY/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<textarea id="taskEmail">
<table>
<tbody id="emailBody"></tbody>
</table>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're passing `undefined` to the TinyMCE  `editor.insertContent()` API when it needs to be a string. See https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent

The cause of that is that your `taskDetails` function doesn't return anything and as such the return value is `undefined`. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do given the example and details, but you may want to change that to something like this instead: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/WOhaab

```
  var taskDetails = function () {
      return '<tr><td style="width:30%">Name</td><td style="width:70%">!EmployeeName!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Task Name</td><td style="width:70%">!TaskName!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Task Description</td><td style="width:70%">!TaskDescription!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Date Assigned</td><td style="width:70%">!DateAssigned!</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="width:30%">Due Date</td><td style="width:70%">!DueDate!</td></tr>';
  }
```

This way your function returns a string and will insert that into the editor where the caret currently is. If you wanted it to overwrite the content instead, then you could use the `editor.setContent()` API instead.

Comment: thanks for the tip! That helped me get some insight. What I ended up doing is not using any editor.x methods and just calling taskDetails() directly in the onAction. Because I'm not trying to just return a string but replace a string on the dom so there is an insertable template for the user.